# share hotkey setup between intellij and goland?

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

What is the easiest way to sync hotkeys between these two IDEs from JetBrains?

I do not want to use go plugin for IntelliJ. I prefer isolation of IDEs for different languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use your JetBrains account to [share settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync) between IDEs with the **Settings Sync** plugin (needs to be installed for GoLand separately). See [related blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-better-synchronization-of-your-settings-across-devices-and-other-improvements/).
2. Use your own git repository where store the settings, by configuring a [settings repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository).

More details in related [documentation article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html).